# Как убрать 2 кнопки с view counter

Tags: webix, counter

в webix-e есть компонент `counter` как у него убрать кнопки пробовал так

```
.webix_inp_counter_next, .myCounter .webix_inp_counter_prev{
    display: none;
}
```

работает , но верстка какая то не красивая писал `border-radius` не работает
http://webix.com/snippet/6ea3e172 вот мой код

и да `view: text` конечно можно использовать но мне нужно именно `counter`

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `style` следующее:

```
.webix_inp_counter_value {
      border-width: 1px;
}
```

или `0px`, чтобы вообще границы убрать.